# convert voltage to sound and back again

Tags: voltage, audio

Is there a simple way of converting a dc voltage to a sound that can be transmitted by the audio of a av sender and then converted back to a voltage.? Out-of-sight farm gate has a video camera attached to a 5.8G wireless "AV" sender for the video. I need to know when the gate is opening. Gate controller shows +12v when opening, zero when not. I just need to be pointed in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Why not put a light on the 12V and point it at the camera? One of those automotive lights will do.

Comment: run a dollar-store radio that needs a 9V battery from the 12v line, wire headphone output to the AV input. tune to static. noise = gate open. a baby monitor turns noise into notifications.

Comment: attach a contact microphone, or an inductive pickup  to the motor

Comment: Thanks people. Jasen got it. I knew there was a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage to frequency and frequency to voltage converters are the devices I think that might be of most interest to you. The [LM331](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm331.pdf) springs to mind as the V2F: -

[image]

And you can also use the LM331 to convert frequency back to voltage: -

[image]

Comment: As it's only a binary on/off there are probably simpler circuits. Particularly for frequency to voltage, it could simply be a filter -> trigger.